# Can you infer that sample is representative from statistical power?

Tags: sample, statistical-power

I have travel times for 1000 routes (origin-destination pairs) and I collected about 12 actual travel time samples by driving some of these routes (randomly selected out of the 1000).

I calculated statistical power of the 12 samples with an online power calculator by using the mean and standard deviation of the 1000 pairs and mean of the sample (alpha = 0.05).

I got a power of 1 which I read somewhere means that the trend in the population would always be detected (from samples of any size). I then used this as a justification that the 12 samples are representative, and compared it with travel times for the sample routes obtained from other sources. A comparison of observed travel time vs predicted ones.

Is this valid, and is inference of this sort achievable from statistical power? Also considering that observed time is being compared to time predicted from long-term averages (for similar driving conditions), how valid should I consider results of such statistical analyses.

Comment: "Power" is a property of a statistical hypothesis test.  What null hypothesis and what alternative hypothesis are you using?

Comment: I'm testing the null hypothesis that the difference between online estimates of travel time and actual travel time for road network travel is insignificant. The alternative hypothesis is that there is a significant difference between online estimates and actual estimates. Although the online estimates are based on long-term averages of travel time on the same day and time the sampling (i.e. driving the routes) was conducted. Thank you.

Comment: Could you explain how you would do that test? Somehow you must have data concerning estimates and other data concerning actual times, but nothing in your post clearly describes such data. Are you trying to imply that the travel times for the 1000 routes are "estimates" of some sort and that you have a sample of them which includes measured travel times? If so, it is difficult to see where a power calculation is relevant: you should be examining the 12 samples you have to see how their estimates differ from their measurements.

Comment: I have data which are estimates and the 12 actual times are what I obtained from driving the routes of 12 estimates I randomly selected (the 1000 routes have estimates of how long it takes to travel each of the routes). Yes I have compared the 12 samples with their estimates via a scatterplot, but I had no idea how else to compare these and thought that a power calculation was necessary, although now I see that I do not understand what power is/does.

Comment: Thank you for that explanation. Please include the information from your comment in the question itself so that readers understand what you are looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Representative* (if that's a concept at all; you may hear the term tossed around, but it means nothing to statisticians) is a function of the design. An example of a representative sample is a simple random sample in which every sample of size 12 out of 1000 is as likely to be drawn as the next (there are ${1000 \choose 12}=1.95\cdot10^{27}$ such samples). An example of a non-representative sample is when you order it alphabetically by the name of the origin point and take the first 12. *Power* is mostly a function of sample size (and, to the lesser extent, of other design decisions, such as balancing the sample sizes of different treatment groups, or degree of data clustering). So one cannot really inform the other. Power calculations nearly necessarily assume unbiased designs (otherwise, why bother collecting the data if you know that your result is biased).

I don't see any way on earth a sample of size 12 could give a power of 1. I reasonably expect that you plugged the numbers in wrong places in that (unspecified) calculator.

Comment: Yes, I found the power of 1 dodgy too. the calculater is here http://www.statisticalsolutions.net/pss_calc.php and I put the mu(0) as the mean of the 1000 routes travel time, while the mu(1) was mean of the 12 samples. Standard deviation was that of the 1000 routes. The routes were randomly selected using Rand() function in Excel. Thank you.

Comment: This post-hoc power computation has little if anything to do with the real power of the test. You probably put $\sigma/\sqrt{1000}$ rather than $\sigma$ as the variance. Who knows, it's your use of the calculator ;)